# Render array value of the nested object Id

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch, nested-object

Is it possible to render the array inside the nested object userId?
I want to get the objects of the userId using the product nested object.

the first image is for users(userID)

[image]

the second image is for products(productId)

[image]

the image is from MongoDB,

As you can see in the second image that userId is nested in products
Right now I can render the name, description, and price.
I also want to fetch my user object: firstName, lastName, etc... using my product nested object

Here is my code for fetch;

```
 export default function Products() {

 const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/products')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

        setProducts(data.map(product => {
                    return (
                        <ProductCard key={product._id} productProp={product} />
                    );
                }))
     })
  }, []);
```

and here is my code to render the object name, description, and price;

```
 export default function ProductCard({productProp}) {

 const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

 const {_id, name, description, price, cart: {userId}} = productProp;

 return (
    (user.isAdmin !== true) ?
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className="p-3 m-3 justify-context-center">
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Subtitle>Description:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{description}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Subtitle>Price:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>PhP {price}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Subtitle>Here is the nested Object:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{userId}</Card.Text>
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to={`/products/${_id}`}>View Product</Link>    
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    :
    <Container>
    
    <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
      <tbody className="justify-content-center">
        <tr>
          <td className="w-25">{name}</td>
          <td className="w-25">{description}</td>
          <td className="w-25">{price}</td>
          <td><Link className="btn btn-danger" to={`/products/${_id}`}>View Details</Link> 
 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </Container>

 )
 }
```

here is my backend code

controller; POST product

```
 module.exports.getAllProducts = () => {
return Product.find({}).then(result => {
    return result;
});
 };
```

router; product

```
router.post("/all", (req, res) => { //need for middleware

productController.getAllProducts().then(resultFromController => 
res.send(resultFromController));

});
```

for user

contoller;

```
module.exports.getAllUsers = () => {
return User.find({}).then(result => {
    return result;
});
};
```

router;

```
router.post("/all", (req, res) => {

userController.getAllUsers().then(resultFromController => 
res.send(resultFromController));

});
```

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: where is the backend code which fetches records from mongo ?

Comment: I'll edit my post and put my backend code.

Comment: checkout the lookup operator, this should help https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/